# Getting absolute path with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to get the absolute path of a file with Perl. The file is located at `/a/b/c/file.txt`. So, I want to get `/a/b/c/`. I can not use `Cwd::cwd()` at the moment, because the actual working directory is `/a/b/`. That is not a bug though because the Perl script is called from `/a/b/`.

So, is there a Perl function to catch that, or do I have to use a regex to find it?

Comment: You need the `relative` or `absolut` path?  if `relative`, `relative` to what?

Comment: The absolute refers to `/a/b/c/file.txt`. I want the `/a/b/c/`. I call it relative! Isn't that true? If I say the parent, then some may think of `c/`.

Comment: In my understanding a relative path is relative to something, like the cwd. an absolut path starts at the root directory

Comment: Well I agree, but as I said the actual working directory in my case is `/a/b`.

Comment: So you want as output?

Comment: So you want not relative path but absolute path of directory that file is located in?

Comment: Yes. The question has been answered though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use File::Basename;
my $path = "/a/b/c/file.txt";
my ($filename, $dir) = fileparse($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

if filenames are without special characters, and are formatted as name.ext, you can use regex such as this one:

```
(.*\/)[\w-]+\.[\w]{3}
```

filename can consist of A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and - (minus)

Comment: Is `-` special character in the file name?

Comment: @mahmood i have added - as allowed char for filename